# Failure to name sheet in Excel VBA using Word page number

Tags: vba, excel

I have imported tables from Word to Excel by VBA and I intend to rename the sheet based on which sheet it came from in the Word document. However, if a page in Word has **more than 1 table** (i.e 2, 3 or more), it will **fail to rename the pages properly (only the first sheet is named properly)**

Can anybody show me what is the correct way to go about solving this recurrent problem?

This is the code I am using. Thank you!

```
For tableStart = tableNo To tableTot
    With .tables(tableStart)
        For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
            For iCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
                Cells(resultRow, iCol) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Text)
            Next iCol
            resultRow = resultRow + 1
        Next iRow

pageNumber = .Range.Characters(1).Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
ActiveSheet.Name = "Page " & pageNumber
    End With
    Sheets.Add  
    resultRow = 2

Next tableStart
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited after OP's clarifications

You must differentiate each worksheet name since Worksheets is a Collection of worksheets in a given Workbook

Since you have more tables in the same page you may build up a worksheet name from table page number *and* that page tables counter, like follows:

```
Dim tablePageNumber As Long, PageNumber As Long, tableCode As Long

With .Tables(tablestart)
    tablePageNumber = .Range.Characters(1).Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
    If tablePageNumber <> PageNumber Then
        pageNumber = tablePageNumber
        tableCode = 1
    Else
        tableCode = tableCode + 1
    End If
End With
ActiveSheet.Name = "Page " & pageNumber & "-" & tableCode
```

Comment: why MUST we differentiate each worksheet name? may i know why it is NOT possible to have 2 ADJACENT worksheets with the SAME name? this is what i originally wanted to do in the first place...

Comment: how would i do a table counter of the SAME page?? like for example, if say page 42 has 3 tables how do i make the tab names be "Page 42-1", "Page 42-2" and "Page 42-3"? Thank you very much for your help

Comment: See edited code. My first answer already fulfilled your _original_ question so please mark it as accepted. Thank you